# Compare two different length arrays using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to compare two arrays with different length  using lodash? The first array contains existing element, the second one contains new and existing element. How can I get new element using lodash?

```
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| Existing| Source of new element | Expected result |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| []      | [1]                   | [1]             |
| [1,2]   | [3,4]                 | [3, 4]          |
| [1,2,3] | [3,4]                 | [4]             |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need lodash for it as its pretty simple done with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as already suggested, but still if you want to rely on lodash then use [_.difference()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#difference).

```js
const
  a = [1, 2, 3],
  b = [3, 4];
  
  console.log(_.difference(b, a));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple filter operation using native `Array#filter()` and `Array#includes()`

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [3, 4],
    unique = b.filter(e => !a.includes(e))

console.log(unique)
```

Or instead of `includes()` pass first array to a `Set` and use `Set#has()`

```js
let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]),
  b = [3, 4],
  unique = b.filter(e => !a.has(e));

console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [_.differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#differenceWith), and pass a comparator which compares two arrays, as in:

```js
const
  a = [1, 2, 3],
  b = [3, 4];
  console.log(_.differenceWith(b, a, _.isEqual));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```